# Duplicated layer not projected to canvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm working with QGIS and have a layer that displays all addresses within a certain area as points on a map. I use the following code to duplicate the layer

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer_type = {'0':'Point', '1':'LineString', '2':'Polygon'}
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_type[str(address_layer.geometryType())] + '?crs=epsg:3011', 'duplicated_layer', 'memory')
feats = [feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
mem_layer.updateFields()
mem_layer_data.addFeatures(feats)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

The new duplicated shows up in the left hand side layer menu, but is not projected to the canvas. Why and how can I project this to the canvas? It has the same CRS as the layer I'm duplicating (EPSG:3011).

Also, the original layer contains all address points in this area. One field in the attribute table is called "Name" and contains the name of the building located at that address, but some addressess have no building in which case Name = NULL. The attribute table of the duplicated layer contains only those observations for which name is not equal to NULL. This is what I want, but I do not fully understand why the whole layer is not duplicated.

If there is a better way to obtain a new layer from the original layer, containing only the addresses where a building is located (i.e. Name!=NULL), suggestions on this is also welcome.